# Change screen orientation during runtime but disable change based on sensor

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an android app. And I want to pick the orientation at the start of the application. But after that, I don't want the orientation to change regardless of how their phone is orientated. I know I could  put android:screenorientation in the manifest file and lock the orientation but I really don't  want to do this. What I want is initially, I will set the orientation to default orientation, let's say landscape. Then, the user will have one chance to change the orientation, after which the orientation will be locked. If the user doesn't pick orientation during the start of the application, then the orientation will be locked to default one. So, I just need to know how to not reload the activity on orientation change. I am not sure if I was good enough in explaining my situation. But thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, first declare the activity in your manifest as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

This implies that now, when the device orientation is called for this Activity, instead of Android recreating it, it will instead call the onConfigurationChanged() method from the Activity. All you have to do now is to declare that method:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // Do nothing -- if that is what you really want !!

    // Check the orientation of the screen if you need to do something
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

you can read more about this at [Android - Handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I would really love a solution in which I don't have to touch the manifest file since I'm planning to let other people use my app as a library. Is it possible to do it without touching the manifest?

Comment: Unfortunately not - as you can see from the docs. It's the only way to let Android know that you will be handling the configuration change for the activity. But with that said, if you are distributing this as a library, why would you want to let the user customize your UI - it's contrary to the design of a library. You might want to provide abstract methods that you force the user to override to achieve the behavior you intend.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will think about it.